# React styled-components Transition not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

Task: Getting a dynamic Transition in react for a sliding SideBar

Problem: The position gets changed dynamically, but there is no smooth transition, it is instant.

Here is the styled-components SideBarContainer:

```
export const SideBarContainer = styled.aside`
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 1000ms;
  ${({isOpen})  => (isOpen && css`
    right: -1000px;
  `)};
`;
```

I also tried it with:

```
right: ${({isOpen})  => (isOpen ? '0px' : '-50vw')};
```

Same Effect.

It gets called here:

```
const SideBar = ({isOpen, toggle, menu}) => {
  return (
    <SideBarContainer isOpen={isOpen} onClick={toggle}>
      ...children
    </SideBarContainer>
  )
}
export default SideBar
```

And finally inside the HeaderComponent:

```
const MainHeader = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen)
  };
  return (
    <NavBar toggle={toggle} menu={menu}/>
    <SideBar isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} menu={menu}/>
  )
}
export default MainHeader
```

However, when i change f.e. the padding manually in the Code, while having the Site open in Browser, the transition works.

My guess is, that because the MainHeader is re-rendered everytime i toggle the SideBar, the animation does not work. So how do i prevent the MainHeader from rerendering?

Comment: yes because you are passing state when state will update it will re-render the MainHeader.

Comment: And how do I change this? 

Comment: Unable to replicate issue: [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sidebar-example-nli0j). If you're still running into an issue, please fork the sandbox, add your code, **save** the codesandbox and post the shareable link.